# Measuring area of Rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

looking at rasters showing change in river channel over time. I have used the raster calculator to calculate the changes e.g. below is the attribute table when subtracting the 2016 raster from the 2015 raster.

[image]

-1 indicates areas of erosion whilst +1 shows areas of new floodplain. 0 is just areas of no change. The cell size is 1.2 so how would I convert the count to an area e.g. m^2?. All of the layers are under the BNG spatial reference

Comment: assuming you're talking about the british national grid, you can just multiply the number of cells with the area of one cell (in your example: 1.2 m x 1.2 m = 1.44 m2). a projected coordinate system always uses a length as reference. for further information visit [this thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/23160).